# how ro remove www from url and also remove index.php on subdomain in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My url is www.exam.domain.ac.in. exam is the sub domain. I want to remove the www and also **index.php** from my **codeigniter application**.

And is it possible to remove the www with php code without using .htaccess?

Please someone help me.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to create .htaccess file in your root folder and then paste following code so it will work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?p=home [S=1]
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?p=home [S=1]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @AshishAwasthi, First of all you need to create .htaccess file in your root folder and then paste above code so it will work fine.
For more information, You will follow [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: Please update your answer as it contains only code if you can add some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to create a file with .htaccess file and  then paste the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # Send request via index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```